# Recognize bridging faces of splits at a plane

Tags: modeling, mesh, scripting, bmesh

I've got a plane with multiple splits. Unfortunately there are undeleted vertices bridging these splits. Is there a way to automatically recognizing these bridges and selecting the faces of them?

[image: Plane in Object Mode]
[image: Plane in Edit Mode with faces selected]

Comment: So Box selecting (press `B` and drag a box) is as a workaround, I guess ?

Comment: unfortunately yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One not always working way is to select similar vertices by amount of connected edges with increasing selection after that.

1. Start by selecting one vertex located in the corner between one of those "bridged faces" and main plane.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to access **Select Similar** menu and choose *Amount of connected edges*. This will select some of vertices of desired part.
3. Increase selection by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to select more.
4. Switch to Face Selection mode and decrease selection by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad -</kbd>.

   [image: Selecting bridged faces - GIF]

This won't work when part of plane between these "bridged faces" is less than 4 polygons. Then on step 3 you'll end up with more selected faces you could deselect in step 4; i.e. the deselection won't work that accurate.